# MySQL Error Code: 1265. Data truncated for column 'p_mode' at row 1

Tags: sql, mysql

Can someone help me with my problem, I don't know whats wrong here.

```
CREATE TABLE project(
    p_id    INT primary key,
    p_name   varchar(50),
    p_budget int,
    p_mode varchar(50),
    p_domain varchar(50),
    p_duration int,
    p_company  varchar(50)
);
```

```
/\* a.  Using data type make sure the project mode is ‘on-site’, ‘online’ or ‘hybrid’\*/
```

```
ALTER TABLE project MODIFY COLUMN p_mode ENUM('on-site','online','hybrid') NOT NULL;
```

> Error Code: 1265. Data truncated for column 'p_mode' at row 1

I will be very glad if you help me.

Comment: seems to wotk just fine https://dbfiddle.uk/lLalbpvT  maybe you have data in that column already, that not correspond to that enum values, so check with `SELECT * FROM project wHERe p_mode not in ('on-site','online','hybrid')`

Comment: Thanks a lot. When I run this queue, I fount that data base has other names, ('On-Site', 'On-line' ,'Hybrid'). So I changed them, and it's working now!!!

Comment: *When I run this queue, I fount that data base has other names, ('On-Site', 'On-line' ,'Hybrid').* While comparing strings one must check that the collation is correct.